# System.NotSupportedException: 'The entity or complex type 'Model' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.'

Tags: asp.net

I want to release data to crystal report through code below. I get an error as image.
[image]

```
        ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
        rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "visitorlist.rpt"));
        rd.SetDataSource(db.Visitor.Select(c => new Visitor()
        {
            name = c.name == null ? "" : c.name,
            surname = c.surname == null ? "" : c.surname,
            organization = c.organization == null ? "" : c.organization,
            input_time = !c.input_time.HasValue ? (DateTime?)System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue : (c.input_time).Value,
            output_time = !c.output_time.HasValue ? (DateTime?)System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue : (c.output_time).Value
        }).ToList());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `ToList` before the `Select` to execute the query before transforming the result.

```
rd.SetDataSource(db.Visitor.ToList().Select(c => new Visitor()
{
    // ...
}));
```